# C#. Webbrowser. Как перехватить переход по ссылке?

Tags: webbrowser, powershell

Добрый день.
Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом можно перехватить переход по ссылке в элементе WebBrowser?
Свойством Navigating (Если да, то покажите пожалуйста простой пример условия, не могу найти никак что-то подходящее).
Мне нужно сделать простое условие например:
По клику на любую ссылку перехватываем переход. Если ссылка содержит какое-либо слово,то переходим. Если нет то нет)

Есть идеи товарищи знатоки?)

Comment: можно выполнить javascript, который будет это условие выполнить.  но ты в коде своем на C#\Powershell не узнаешь об этом

Comment: если у кнопни ксть href, то можно оттуда доставать инфу

Comment: В бесконечном цикле следим за URL документа. Если не нравится URL возвращаем прежний